# java - looping through values

Tags: java, for-loop

I am trying to create a nested for loops that will generate all the pairs in a range specified by the user, ranging from negative values to positive values.  It is a little tough to explain, but here is the code I have:

```
public class test method {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

    int a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int b = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    int c = 3;
    int d = 4;

    for (int i = -a; i <= a; i++)
        for (int j = -b; j <= b; j++) {

            System.out.println(a+" and "+b+" vs "+c+" and "+d+"\n");

        }

    }

}
```

Given command line arguments 1 and 2, my desired output would be something like:

-1 and -2 vs 3 and 4

-1 and -1 vs 3 and 4

-1 and 0 vs 3 and 4

-1 and 1 vs 3 and 4

-1 and 2 vs 3 and 4

0 and -2 vs 3 and 4

0 and -1 vs 3 and 4

0 and 0 vs 3 and 4

0 and 1 vs 3 and 4

0 and 2 vs 3 and 4

1 and -2 vs 3 and 4

1 and -1 vs 3 and 4

1 and 0 vs 3 and 4

1 and 1 vs 3 and 4

1 and 2 vs 3 and 4

Comment: Are the ranges `[a,b]` and `[c,d]`? Why are you printing these numbers (a,b,c,d) and not `(i,j)`? I am not sure I am following what the question exactly is :|

Comment: What's going wrong with the code you have?  Is it failing to compile (well, the exact code you posted above won't compile because a class name has to be a single identifier)?  Is it throwing an exception?  Is it producing the wrong answer?  We can't read your mind to learn what needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the lack of brackets in the first for is a problem in the copy & paste, but if that's your real code you've got a problem there.

```
a = Math.abs(a);
b = Math.abs(b);

for (int i = -a; i <= a; i++) {
    for (int j = -b; j <= b; j++) {
        System.out.println(i+" and "+j+" vs "+c+" and "+d+"\n");
    }
}
```

Two things. First of all you should be printing `i` and `j` and second you should also consider negative values. Your `for`'s will fail since `-a` if `a = -1` will result in

```
for (int i = 1; i <= -1; i++)
```

The condition will not be met and the iteration won't take place. By doing `Math.abs` you get the absolute value of the inputs and you can do the iteration from that negative value to the positive one. If both `a` and `b` are positive the `abs` method will return the same values (assigning `a` and `b` with the same values they already have).

Whatever should be done with `c` and `d` remains to be seen. Your desired output says you leave them as they are so I won't touch them by now.

Comment: This was extremely helpful.  Good thinking making the inputs absolute values.  Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Ted You're welcome. Also, remember you can accept an answer if it was trully helpful by clicking the green tick under the question's score.

Answer (score 0):

looks reasonable, exception for the '-a' business (and printing the wrong variables)

Assuming a/b are always positive, try

```
for (int i = (0-a); i <= a; i++)
    for (int j = (0-b); j <= b; j++) {
        System.out.println(i+" and "+j+" vs "+c+" and "+d+"\n");
```